# Upload dataframe as dataset in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

after download a dataset, convert to dataframe and manipulate it.. how can I upload again as new dataset in Azure Machine Learning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow the steps below: 
1. write dataframe to a local file (e.g. csv, parquet)

```
local_path = 'data/prepared.csv'
df.to_csv(local_path)
```

2. upload the local file to a datastore on the cloud

```
# azureml-core of version 1.0.72 or higher is required
# azureml-dataprep[pandas] of version 1.1.34 or higher is required
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
resource_group = 'xxxxxx'
workspace_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
# get the datastore to upload prepared data
datastore = workspace.get_default_datastore()
# upload the local file from src_dir to the target_path in datastore
datastore.upload(src_dir='data', target_path='data')
```

3. create a dataset referencing the cloud location

```
ds = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(datastore.path('data/prepared.csv'))
```

Comment: So, to upload a dataset to datastore from a dataframe, first it's required to save it as CSV or parquet (or similar) and then upload? Is this the way that replace the Dataset.from_pandas_dataframe() method?

Comment: Based on the current capability, yes, you need to save to local file and upload. Dataset.register_pandas_dataframe() is on our roadmap.